# How to update data in database with query that not change original value?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Lets say I have multiple commands like 5000 which updates some column and row in databse - it is number for example

```
UPDATE salary SET money=2000000 WHERE person=55;
```

Is there any way how to update such data without destroying the original value? Lets say the money has already exiting and different value? I have searched google and MySQL manual but I did not find any useful query for this. Is there any way how to update such data without destroying the original value? Thank you.

Comment: You mean something like `set money = money + 5`?

Comment: money + value inside money already existing (always different)

Comment: me neither, do you or don't you, want to update the value? `Is there any way how to update such data without destroying the original value?` the original value or values simply get updated.

Comment: I want to update the value with number but add it to existing number in "money" column. Something like SET money=20000+numberalreadyexistinginsidemoney

Comment: @Byakugan I see you want to increment, by a different value set in a different column, thats within the same table or row? do you want to double the salary `UPDATE salary SET money = 2*money WHERE person=55;`

Comment: answer is in the very first comment

Comment: I do not want to add constant +5 but instead of +5 I need the value already existing what is so hard to understand? Table is already filled with som data so as "money" and I need to add some value to existing one and I did not find any besides "UPDATE" query but it overwrites the original value and I already have like thousands of queries I posted above and do not have time to look for every one of it and make special update command or them all

Comment: @Byakugan, if you don't want to change a value, use INSERT to create a new row.

Comment: Pretty much everything is hard to understand because instead of giving more information, you're reiterating what you've said before. Where are these other existing values coming from? Do you want to update one row with the value of another row?

Comment: Heh ... Once again ... there is table with 2000 persons and different money value already existing in database. Now I have 2000 update queries which should update the original value with new one + old one. Is it understandable now? :)

Comment: I get these values from one program ... http://paste2.org/p/2055777 I can edit them with some script but which command to use to save original values and add them to updated values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess was almost perfect.

```
UPDATE salary SET money=money+2000000 WHERE person=55;
```